# ReactJS: How to fetch data from API on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am making an [app](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bartik-k49bb) to fetch data from a recipeDB API, and right now I need to click on the search button have it console.log some data. Right now it is giving me a network error when attempting to fetch the resource. I have my code setup like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const API_ID = "0fc98505";
  const API_KEY = "5e81ce76845f459b53f9fbe775e81e53";

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);




  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data)
    console.log(data);

  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getRecipes}>Retrive data</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "it is giving me a network error" show the **actual** error message.

Comment: Seems like "has been blocked by CORS policy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a network error, this means that your request is executed. I think the error here lies in your APP_ID and API_KEY. Another reason might be CORS. For more details visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) page.
Also you can check out «Network» tab in your developer tools(F12) where error description is sometimes shown in response body.